# Pandas – save to csv replaces columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have problem with saving pandas DataFrame to csv. I run code on jupyter notebook and everything works fine. After runing the same code on server columns values are saved to random columns…

```
csvPath = r''+str(pathlib.Path().absolute())+ '/products/'+brand['file_name']+'_products.csv'
productFrame.to_csv(csvPath,index=True)
```

I've print DataFrame before saving – looks as it should be. After saving, I open file and values ale mixed.

How to make it always work in the proper way?

Comment: Try opening it in some text editor and check for the extra comma's? By mixed what do you mean?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the dataframe, and a sample of the file output as plaintext

Comment: If you opening your in excel, then there's a possibility of values mixing

Comment: There is no extra comma's. Mixed – there are named columns A, B, C etc. And values which should be in column B are in the column C. Values from column C are in column A…

Comment: @bigbounty that's right… I was opening in VS Code plugin, which generate excel like table, and that was problem…

Comment: Cool @user37510. So, problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the column order when exporting to csv, use

```
df[cols].to_csv()
```

where `cols` is a list of column names in the desired order.